# Most efficient way to compare an Entity Model to a DTO Model in C#/LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-core

I am passing back a DTO object with a more than a dozen properties that I want to update in the database only if one or more of the properties differ with the current EF object. What is the most programmatically simple way to accomplish this using C# and Lambda-syntax LINQ?

Comment: create extension methods for models

Comment: If any other way let me know it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this example.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Client/UpdateClient")]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult UpdateClient(ClientDTO client)
    {
        var user = GetLoggerUser(BOAccount);            
        client.LastModifiedBy = user.EmailAddress;
        client.LastModifiiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;            
        var resultclient = BOClient.UpdateClient(client, user);
        return Json(resultclient);
    }
    // BOClient.UpdateClient
    public ClientDTO UpdateClient(ClientDTO client, UserDTO user)
    {
        var _clientRepo = ((UnitOfWork)_unitOfWork).ClientRepository;
        var _client = _clientRepo.Get(filter: u => u.Id == client.Id).Single();

        _client.Id = client.Id;
        _client.Phone = client.Phone;
        _client.Address = client.Address;
        _client.Email = client.Email;
        _client.Type = client.Type;
        _client.Name = client.Name;

        object _transaction = _unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            _clientRepo.Update(_client);

            _unitOfWork.CommitTransaction(_transaction);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _unitOfWork.RollbackTransaction(_transaction);

            return client;
        }
        finally
        {
            _unitOfWork.DestroyTransaction(_transaction);
        }
        return client;
    }
```

And Created model is

```
namespace OptiLeadInfrastructure.Models
{
    public class ClientDTO
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> Type { get; set; }
        public string logo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> LastModifiiedOn { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ClientDetailDTO> ClientDetails { get; set; }
    }   public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: If you create model from database and use it, it will be easy to do CRUD action.